# record audio and play it issue

Tags: java, android, audio-recording

I am trying to make simple app just for learning purpose thats record an audio clip then upload the file to the firebase and here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private StorageReference mStorage;

Button recordeButton ;
TextView recorderLable ;

private MediaRecorder recorder;
private String fileName = null ;

private static final String LOG_TAG = "AudioRecordTest";
private static final int REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION = 200;

private MediaPlayer player = null;

ProgressDialog progressDialog ;

// Requesting permission to RECORD_AUDIO
private boolean permissionToRecordAccepted = false;
private String [] permissions = {Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO};

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode){
        case REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION:
            permissionToRecordAccepted  = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
            break;
    }
    if (!permissionToRecordAccepted ) finish();

}







    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    recordeButton = findViewById(R.id.recordeButton) ;
    recorderLable = findViewById(R.id.recordeLable) ;

        fileName = getExternalCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
        fileName += "/audiorecordtest.3gp";

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this) ;





        recordeButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                startRecording();
                recorderLable.setText("recording started");
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                stopRecording();
                recorderLable.setText("recording stopped");
            }

            return false ;
        }
    });




}

private void startRecording() {
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile(fileName);

    try {
        recorder.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
    }

    recorder.start();
}

private void stopRecording() {
    recorder.stop();
    recorder.release();
    recorder = null;

    uploadAudio();

}

private void uploadAudio() {

    progressDialog.setMessage("UPLOADING ...");
    progressDialog.show();

    String uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString() ;



    final StorageReference filePath = mStorage.child("Audio").child(uniqueID + ".mp3") ;

    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(fileName)) ;

    filePath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

            progressDialog.dismiss();
            recorderLable.setText("AUDIO UPLOADED \uD83D\uDE0A");

            filePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {

                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        final Uri path = task.getResult();
                        Log.i("AUDIO_URI", path.toString());
                    }



                }
            }) ;

        }
    }) ;

  }
}
```

the problem is I've uploaded the file successfully but when I try to play it in the firebase nothing happen and length of the file is 0:00 which means that there is a problem in recording process  not in uploading

Comment: @TamirAbutbul when you remove the Android Studio tag, **make sure you tag appropriately**. From the code, you can tell this is Android (if you're not sure, you can Google `AppCompatActivity` and that'll also validate it), and removing the android-studio tag should be done in combination with adding the Android tag. I've added it already, just keep that in mind in the future

Comment: I was sure that i added the android tag  - my bad here and thx for notice

Comment: looks like no one knows the answer for my problem